# Line breaks when using CSS "display:inline"

Tags: css

I have successfully managed to get a `<p>` follow a `<h>` on the same line, however I wish to repeat this on a new line, but the next `<h>` is following on from the last `<p>` - what should I do?

I have tried various "clear" options, but none break the inline.  I don't really want to use `<br>` or have an empty `<p>`, not overly happy to surround with `<div>` either.

Note - I have tried removing the `inline` from the second `<h>` element, and while that does place the `<h>` on a new line, the following `<p>` ends up on it's own new line too.

CSS

```
.inline {display: inline;}

.newline {clear: left;}
```

HTML

```
<h5 class="inline">Heading:</h5>

<p class="inline">Some text.</p>

<h5 class="inline newline">Next Heading:</h5>

<p class="inline">Some more text.</p>
```

This is the result I want to achieve:

> **Heading:** Some text.
>
> **Next Heading** Some more text.

but instead I am getting this:

> **Heading:** Some text. **Next Heading** Some more text.

Any suggestions - trying to keep the code as simple and neat as possible.

[Update]

For the time being I am  going to add an empty div as suggested by hafid2com, using the following (just adding height to achieve the desired result):

`.clear { clear: both; display: block; content: ""; width: 100%;  }`

`<div class="clear"></div>`

As shown in the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/rxAnk/5/

Comment: Sounds like you should be floating them instead.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Add this:

HTML:

```
<h5 class="inline">Heading:</h5>

<p class="inline">Some text.</p>

<div class="clear"></div>

<h5 class="inline">Next Heading:</h5>

<p class="inline">Some more text.</p>
```

CSS:

```
.inline {display: inline;}

.clear{
  clear: both;
  display: block;  
  content: "";
  width: 100%;  
}
```

Comment: Oh well, an empty div it is, added `height` to it.  Here is the new updated fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/rxAnk/5/

Comment: I have accepted this as my preferred solution for now, but if there is anyway of achieving the same result without the empty `<div>`, or the floats and spans above, I am all ears.  Thank you.

Comment: Ok Thanks,Wath about this:

.inline {display: inline;}
  
.newline:before{
  display: block;   
  content: "";
  width: 100%; 
  *zoom: 1;
}

http://codepen.io/Denguir/pen/GymuL

Answer (score 2):

There are a number of ways you can achieve the desired effect:

1) You could use `float` rather than `display`:

```
<style type="text/css">
    h5 {float:left;clear:left;}
    p {float:left;}
</style>

<h5>Heading:</h5>
<p>Some text.</p>
<h5>Next Heading:</h5>
<p>Some more text.</p>
```

2) You could use `<strong>` instead of `<h5>` and put your headings inside the `<p>` tags (thanks to @Ralph.m for pointing out that `<h5>` tags within `<p>` would be invalid):

```
<p><strong>Heading:</strong> Some text.</p>
<p><strong>Next Heading:</strong> Some more text.</p>
```

3) You could keep your `display:inline;` styles and wrap each `<h5>` and `<p>` in a `<div>`:

```
<style type="text/css">
    h5, p {display:inline;}
</style>

<div>
    <h5>Heading:</h5>
    <p>Some text.</p>
</div>
<div>
    <h5>Next Heading:</h5>
    <p>Some more text.</p>
</div>
```

Comment: OK, I don't know why I didn't think about floats.  I think I tried `h5.inline {float:left;clear:left;}` and `p.inline {float:left;}` so as not to break the rest of the page  but it is breaking everything :(    is there anyway to do it with `display`?

Comment: You can keep inline `H5` instead of the `strong`.

Comment: It might, but I will not put a `<h>` inside a `<p>` - it is semantically incorrect and, I believe,  will break in some browsers.

Comment: Using either `<strong>` or `<span>` with an assigned style WILL work, but I was hoping to keep them as headings as opposed to paragraphs, but the body of text with them is not heading material.  From a semantics PoV, setting the whole section to `<h>` or `<p>` is wrong, but so is using HTML to affect the layout (`<br>` or empty `<p>`).

Comment: @user2329155 I've added another solution that maintains the <h5> tags - how does that work for you?

Comment: It works - but requires more styling to get a blank line between lines.  I am currently debating my current solution (see update to original question) of using an empty `<div>` to separate the lines and adding styling to the inline class that puts 1 line of spacing underneath.  For now I am sticking with the empty `<div>` I think, as I am using this inline styling elsewhere and don't want to break the page flow and design.  Thank you for your input though, very helpful.

Comment: @Escribblings You could always add a `margin-bottom` to the wrapping `<div>`.

Answer (score 1):

I would question if you are really using the right markup here. Remember that HTML markup is not presentational, but semantic. It's rarely, if ever, good semantics to use H5s, unless they help to break up content headed by an H4 etc.

Without knowing the context here, I'd be suggesting something like this:

```
<style type="text/css">
  p span {font-weight: bold;}
</style>

<p><span>Heading:</span> Some text.</p>
<p><span>Next Heading:</span> Some more text.</p>
```

Of course, if headings are indeed needed, replace `<p>` with `<hx>`, though I really doubt this is appropriate.

(As an aside, an alternative to `float` is `display: inline-block`. But never nest an `<h5>` inside a `<p>`, as that's not valid coding.)

Comment: `<span>` is an option I suppose, but technically they are headings - yes they do follow on down the page from `<h1>`, `<h2>`, `<h3>` and `<h4>` and no, they are not nested inside `<p>` tags.  Basically, `<h1>` is the page heading, `<h2>` is the pages sub-heading, `<h3>` is the section heading, `<h4>` is the sub-section heading and `<h5>` is like a line heading within that sub-section that would make semantic sense on the same line (as I am trying to achieve) or above the text as a normal heading.

Comment: What would be more semantically correct?  To use `<span>` and `font-weight: bold;` on what is technically a heading, or to use empty `<p>` or `<br>` tags to break the line?

Comment: If it's a heading, certainly use a heading tag. If you want to style parts of it differently, then I'd say use a hook like `span`. But if the text that sits inline with it is not heading text, then what I suggested—putting it all in one element—isn't the best way to go.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with BoltClock, use float. How about this:

CSS

```
.inline {float:left;}
.clear {clear:both;}
```

HTML

```
<h5 class="inline">Heading:</h5>

<p class="inline">Some text.</p>
<div class="clear"></div>

<h5 class="inline">Next Heading:</h5>

<p class="inline">Some more text.</p>
```

Here's a fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/rxAnk/

Comment: I see you are using an empty div to create the line break.  I have updated the fiddle with my code - I commented out the `.more` class as the js wasn't working and it was hiding everything.  Here is the [updated fiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/rxAnk/4/)

Answer (score 1):

If you do not want to manually insert additional markup, try this approach which injects a newline and using `:before` and sets it to wrap on the whitespace. `\A`, or `\00000a`, is the ISO-10646 character code  (U+000A) CSS accepts.

http://jsfiddle.net/TwoD/ujhwLouc/

CSS

```css
.inline {display: inline;}
h5.inline.newline:before {content: '\A'; white-space:pre-line;}
```

HTML

```html
<h5 class="inline">Heading:</h5>
<p class="inline">Some text.</p>   
<h5 class="inline newline">Next Heading:</h5>
<p class="inline">Some more text.</p>
```